# Can I use this power supply with my Arduino?

Tags: power

I am new to Arduino and electronics in general.

I am working on a project where I would ultimately like to power the project from 220V AC (Wall light switch) (I want to replace the light switch with one of my own design).

I will want to feed power to the arduino directly from the 220V connecting wires in the light switch cavity.

This power source is 5V (I know the Arduino needs 9-12V), but I will use a USB connector, wired onto my AC/DC power source, to power the Arduino.

[Power Source](https://www.banggood.com/AC-DC-Isolated-AC-110V-220V-To-DC-5V-600mA-Constant-Voltage-Switch-Power-Supply-Converter-Module-p-1088877.html)

**Ratings:**

```
AC85 - 264V or  DC110 - 370V wide voltage input
DC 5V(+/ -0.2V) 600mA isolated output
Input Current: 0.0273A/115VAC  0.014A/230VAC
Input surge current: 20A (230VAC)
Frequency range: 50/60 Hz
Operating Temperature: -30 - 70 ℃
Relative humidity: 20%- 90%
Rated power: 3W
Output efficiency: 80%
```

I don't really know why yet (this is part of figuring that out), but I have the feeling that the arduino would want a linear power source, rather than a switching power source. (Because linear is cleaner power?)

Regardless, I am asking the question as if this power source will do the job, and if not, why not? (Why not a switching PSU) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that power supply is ideal for powering an Arduino (an Arduino doesn't care if it's linear or switching, and a linear regulator that goes from 220V to 5V is called a *furnace*, and you don't want one of those...)

**HOWEVER** unless you have a very strange wiring setup in your house, under normal circumstances *there is no 220V supply in the switch*.  You normally have *live in*, *switched live out* and ***NO*** neutral connection.

That means you don't have the connections you need to wire your power supply up to.

By the way: *if you didn't already know that then you are not qualified to mess around with home wiring and you should leave it to the professionals.*

Comment: Well well well... I DID indeed forget about that. I am no electrician, and to be honest I have never opened a light socket, but I do know (forgot obviously) that they are not powered by a neutral and positive. I got whisked away so fast on the cool project idea, that I did not consider that. I just wrongly assumed "there must be power there" because it turns the light on.

Thanks for getting me back on track! ;-P

Comment: actually new code recommends/requires putting a neutral at each switch location exactly to enable smart switches.

Comment: @ratchetfreak ... depending on where you live...  codes aren't universal.

Comment: Being in South Africa in a rather "long ago built house", I probably do not have a neutral wire in the cavity. I will inspect.

Comment: in the USA, we've been running neutrals in practice since the 90s and in code since 2011.